# Python Selenium - Login error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to input login details into GMAIL with the below coode

```
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass

chromedriver = 'C:\Python34\Scripts\chromedriver'



driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get('http://www.google.com/adwords/')

signin = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ignore-channel')
signin.click()

email = input('Enter your Email ID : ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password :')
email = driver.find_element_by_id('Email')
email.send_keys(email)
passwd = driver.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
passwd.send_keys(password)

submit = driver.find_element_by_id('signIn')
submit.click()
tools = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Keyword')
tools[0].click()
```

When i enter the login/pass details. Python returns the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/SEO.py", line 18, in <module>
    email.send_keys(email)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

any idea where i might be wrong?

KJ

Comment: Why are you using same variables for user input and WebElements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these lines from your code:
Line number 15

```
email = input('Enter your Email ID : ')
```

Line number 17

```
email = driver.find_element_by_id('Email')
```

Line number 18

```
email.send_keys(email)
```

So you are assigning your email string to the variable name 'email' and then again assigning the 'webelement' into the same variable name 'email'. So when the code tries to do sendkeys at line 18, it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. such a crap mistake !